# How to start a transaction in a non-spring-managed bean?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I've got a Spring 3.2.8 application in which I've got a particular case in where I want to start a transaction within a Context Listener.

I know and realize that the listener is not a spring managed bean, so I'm not entirely sure how to go about marking my method as being `@Transactional`.  I've tried marking the bean as `@Configurable`, but that does not seem to do the trick; I'm guessing b/c the application server instantiates this bean before the spring context is loaded.

I've checked the transaction status with `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()`, but I get a `NoTransactionException` thrown which occurs when there is no managed open transaction.

Is there anything within Spring that will allow me to mark this method as part of transaction?

```
@Configurable
public class PatchEngineContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    // SLF4J logger
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PatchEngineContextListener.class);


    // HELPERS
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    @Autowired private PatchService patchService;
    @Autowired private PatchEngine patchEngine;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        // get the app context
        appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
        appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

        logger.info( TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().toString() );

        try {
            setPatchEngineUser();
            patchEngine.execute();
            clearPatchEngineUser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(TransactionAspectSupport.java:110)
    at com.ia.system.patch.engine.PatchEngineContextListener.contextInitialized(PatchEngineContextListener.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Web.xml:

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Patch Engine launched after spring finishes setting up its context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.ia.system.patch.engine.PatchEngineContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:spring-configured/>
```

Comment: You can wire TransactionManager to your bean and then manage transactions manually.

Comment: Why does it have to be a `ServletContextListener`? Can't you make it a Spring `ApplicationListener` with the appropriate event?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I likely could; I did not know about Spring's ApplicationListener.  I am having trouble finding documentation about it; google searches don't immediately point me to good spring docs - only blogs how to implement it.  Do you know where I would find the associated docs about Spring's event mechanisms?

Comment: @jakub.petr - Thanks; I had not thought of that.  Although I think I will first investigate Sotirios' concept first.

Comment: Start at the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html). Look at the implementing classes (and their subclasses) of `ApplicationEvent`. The IoC documentation should also have an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Perfect; found it.  Thanks.  Will got through this and try to make it a Spring event listener instead.  I agree; it is more appropriate to the use-case than a servlet listener.  Can post your recommendation as an answer instead of just a comment so I can credit you appropriately?